# Issue regarding UIScrollView as a subivew of a UIPanGesture-enabled view

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uipangesturerecognizer

Here is the scenario:

I have a scrollView as a subview of a view that has a UIPanGestureRecognizer added. The pan gesture only applies in one direction, let's say from left to right.

What I'm trying to achieve is: If the scrollView.contentOffset.x == 0 and the user is panning from left to right I want the PanGesture to work, otherwise I want to let the scrollView to work as usual.

I tried

- Implementing `hitTest:withEvent:` on the scrollView's superview where I can check for the contentOffset, but there is no data about the gesture direction.
- Implementing `touchesShouldBegin:withEvent:inContentView:` in the scrollView, but again, no data about direction.

The problem seems to be the moments, If I want to make this kind of checks after a view is handling a gesture event, there is no chance to cancel it and re-send the event to another view.

Is there a workaround for this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Setup a delegate for the UIPanGestureRecognizer you have added to the superview and implement

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer { 
    if(scrollView.contentOffset.x != 0){
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I believe this is a solution for a case when the PanGesture invalidates the scrollView's interaction... my scenario is the opposite.